# How to create a parent class for the following 'monster' classes?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import monsters


class numMonst1():

    def __init__(self, name, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.name = name
        self.colour = "blue"
        self.size = 30

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " @ " + str(self.pos)

    def stepChange(self, limits):
        xmov = random.choice([-1,0,1])
        ymov = random.choice([-1,0,1])
        self.pos[0] += xmov
        self.pos[1] += ymov

    def getSize(self):
        return self.size

    def getColour(self):
        return self.colour

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getPos(self):
        return self.pos

class numMonst2():

    def __init__(self, name, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.name = name
        self.colour = "purple"
        self.size = 15

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " @ " + str(self.pos)

    def stepChange(self, limits):
        xmov = random.choice([-1,0,1])
        ymov = random.choice([-1,0,1])
        self.pos[0] -= xmov
        self.pos[1] -= ymov

    def getSize(self):
        return self.size

    def getColour(self):
        return self.colour

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getPos(self):
        return self.pos
    
class numMonst3():

    def __init__(self, name, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.name = name
        self.colour = "red"
        self.size = 20

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " @ " + str(self.pos)

    def stepChange(self, limits):
        xmov = random.choice([-1,0,1])
        ymov = random.choice([-1,0,1])
        self.pos[0] -= xmov
        self.pos[1] -= ymov

    def getSize(self):
        return self.size

    def getColour(self):
        return self.colour

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getPos(self):
        return self.pos
    
    
limits = (30, 20)

def sim(T, c, t, x, j, a):     # timesteps and creature counts
    monsterlist = []

    for i in range(c):
        randX = random.randint(0,limits[0])
        randY = random.randint(0,limits[1])
        monsterlist.append(numMonst1("Bruce", [randX,randY])) # blue monster
        
    for i in range(t):
        randX = random.randint(0,limits[0])
        randY = random.randint(0,limits[1])
        monsterlist.append(numMonst2("Bruce", [randX,randY])) # purple Monster
        
    for i in range(a):
        randX = random.randint(0,limits[0])
        randY = random.randint(0,limits[1])
        monsterlist.append(numMonst3("Bruce", [randX,randY])) # purple Monster
        
    for i in range(T):
        print("TIMESTEP ",i,)
        for m in monsterlist:
            m.stepChange(limits)

        plt.xlim(0,limits[0])
        plt.ylim(0,limits[1])
        xvalues = []
        yvalues = []
        sizes = []
        colour = []
        for m in monsterlist:
            xvalues.append(m.pos[0])
            yvalues.append(m.pos[1])
            sizes.append(m.getSize())
            colour.append(m.getColour())
            
        plt.scatter(xvalues, yvalues, s = sizes, color = colour)    
        plt.show()

sim(6, 5, 10, 5, 10, 6)     # you can copy or update and call the code from 2b
```

Each class is its own `monster` that gets displayed as a dot in its respective color and sizes. The main goal is to create a parent class and store the required data while still displaying the same output of 3 different dots in their respective parameters.

I know that each class is its own repetition yet still displays a different output as per their given parameters. I need to create a parent class for these monsters but I don't know how to store them all in one class and call them forward.

Answer (score 1):

Write only one `Monster` class with `colour` and `size` as parameters

```
class Monster():

    def __init__(self, name, pos, size=10, colour='white'):
        self.pos = pos
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour
        self.size = size
```